# SQL COUNT - Output table with two COUNT columns with differing WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle-apex

I have the need to generate a report in Oracle APEX that is similar to the example below:

```
 PROJECT     OPEN_ISSUE_COUNT     CLOSED_ISSUE_COUNT
 W-1         3                    1
 X-2         1                    2
 Y-3         5                    3
 Z-4         2                    1
```

Where `OPEN_ISSUE_COUNT` and `CLOSED_ISSUE_COUNT` are generated by a `SQL COUNT` statement. The table being queried looks like this:

```
 ISSUE_#     ISSUE_STATUS     ASSOCIATED_PROJECT
 1A          OPEN             W-1
 1B          OPEN             W-1
 1C          OPEN             W-1
 2A          CLOSED           W-1
 2B          OPEN             X-2
 2C          CLOSED           X-2
 3A          CLOSED           X-2 
 etc...
```

So in one query I need to count for `OPEN_ISSUE_COUNT` and `CLOSED_ISSUE_COUNT` where `ISSUS_STATUS = 'OPEN'` and `ISSUS_STATUS = 'CLOSED'` respectively and `GROUP BY` `ASSOCIATED_PROJECT`.

Does that make sense? Obviously I can easily do this for one of the two statuses, but have been unable to come up with any viable solution for what I am describing here. I have looked over some stuff here and elsewhere online and did not see something similar. Let me know what you guys think. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `count()` only counts non-null values, this should work:

```
select associated_project as project,
count(case when issue_status='OPEN' then 1 else null end) as open_issue_count,
count(case when issue_status='CLOSED' then 1 else null end) as closed_issue_count
from table
group by associated_project;
```

Of course, this assumes that the only valid values for `issue_status` are `'OPEN'` AND `'CLOSED'`.  If this isn't the case--and if you want those other statuses counted--then adjust the query accordingly.

Comment: @Sebas - This 'trick' also allows you to do things like `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN x THEN some_id ELSE NULL END)`.  It's a lovely little tool.

Comment: yeah, neat :-) I guess it is transportable to mysql as well! yay!

Comment: By the way, the `else null` part isn't needed since null is the default if not supplied

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is with the new PIVOT feature:

```
with issue_data as (
  select associated_project as project, issue_status from issues
)
select project, open, closed
  from issue_data
       pivot ( count(*) for issue_status in ('OPEN' as open, 'CLOSED' as closed) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
sum(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) as open,
sum(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed
from table
where  <other restrictions>
```